# How do i get the bootstrap div to align center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

Am trying to edit a pre-existing code, need to align the image and text to the center of the column

```
<div class="vc_row wpb_row section vc_row-fluid grid_section center" style="background-color:#f6f6f6; padding-top:46px; text-align:center;">
<div class="section_inner clearfix center">
<div class="section_inner_margin clearfix center">
    <div class="vc_col-sm-3 wpb_column vc_column_container center">
    <div class="wpb_wrapper center">
    <div class="q_team" style="background-color:#f6f6f6;">
        <div class="q_team_inner">
        <div class="q_team_image"><img src="wp-content/uploads/profiles/exaple.jpg" alt="" /></div>
        <div class="q_team_text" >
        <div class="q_team_text_inner">
        <div class="q_team_title_holder">
            <h6 class="q_team_name" style = "color: #2f2f2f;">RC</h6>
            <span style = "color: #2196F3;">Chairman & Managing Director</span>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="q_team_social_holder"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
            <div class="separator  transparent center  " style="margin-top: 30px;margin-bottom: 0px;"></div>
    </div> 
    </div> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

the 1st 3 div elemets define the ROW and the rest define colums, can add more colums as needed

Comment: Please describe div align center vertically or horizontally?

Comment: please tell @Ajoy

Comment: sry for not replying. did not see your message @Rayees AC but its solved

Comment: No problem bro @Ajoy